# Metric tensor for resulting manifold defined at coordinate $x$ of n-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ a smooth function, $G_f \ N = M \times \mathbb{R}$ the graph of $f$. Equip $G_f$ with the Riemannian metric $h$ induced from the product metric on $N$. The graph $G_f$ is diffeomorphic to $M$ via the map $F(x)=(x,f(x))$. What is the formula for the pull-back metric $F^*(h)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $M\times f$?

Comment: The function $f$ is submersed in given manifold $\mathcal{M}$, which suggests the product space.

Comment: This still makes no sense. Are you meaning to say the graph of $f$ as a submanifold of $\mathcal M\times\Bbb R$? Moreover, your metric is wrong for the paraboloid.

Comment: Yes, it means $\mathcal{M} \times \mathbb{R}$. What is the metric for a paraboloid then?

Comment: You parametrize by $F(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y))$ and, for example, $g_{11}=F_x\cdot F_x$. Analogously with polar coordinates: $F(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, f(r,\theta))$.

Comment: Indeed. sir. A more general case is missing. :-(

Comment: I am not sure: In polar coordinates, the parametrization $F(r, \varphi) = (r, \varphi, f(r, \varphi))$ says that $g_{11} = 1+f_r^2$ and $g_{\varphi} = I + f_\varphi \, f_\varphi^\intercal$.

Comment: I changed the statement for a better reader comprehension.

Comment: The question is still a mess. I think, what you meant to ask is the following: "Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $f\in C^\infty(M)$ a smooth function, $G_f\subset N=M\times {\mathbb R}$ the graph of $f$. Equip $G_f$ with the Riemannian metric $h$ induced from the product metric on $N$. The graph $G_f$ is diffeomorphic to $M$ via the map $F(x)=(x,f(x))$. What is the formula for the pull-back metric $F^*(h)$?"

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I want. I thank you to clarify it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I editted the statement in the same way you pose the problem. Lets hope it is sufficient for us to have a direction for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ds^2$ be the Riemannian metric on $M$ (which is an $n$-dimensional manifold). Then for the map $F(x)=(x,f(x))$, the pull-back $F^*(ds^2 + dt^2)$ of the product metric $ds^2 + dt^2$ on $M\times {\mathbb R}$ equals
$$
ds^2 + (df)^2.
$$
In terms of local coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n)$ on $M$, this metric equals
$$
ds^2 + \sum_{i, j} f_{x_i} f_{x_j} dx_i dx_j= 
$$
$$
ds^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n f_{x_k}^2 dx_k^2 + \sum_{i<j} 2 f_{x_i} f_{x_j} dx_i dx_j. 
$$
Here $f_{x_k}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$, $k=1,...,n$.

Comment: Does it change much in case the n dimensional manifold $M$ is an abstract surface submerged in a $n+1$ dimensional continuous vector space $X$ with basis $B_X$ and inner product $\langle \cdot, \, \cdot \rangle$?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I do not understand your comment at all.

Comment: Imagine a surface which instead of being immersed on $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is on vector space $X$. On it, there is an inner product $\langle \, , \, \rangle$. I want additionally do define a function value $f(\cdot)$ for each coordinate of this surface and obtain its induced metric. Did I make myself clearer than before now?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto No idea. The manifold in my question is *abstract*, not embedded (or immersed) anywhere. If you have a new question, then ask a separate question.